# Using an audio stream URL with wpaudio or any other such script

Tags: audio, streaming, stream, audio-streaming

I have bunch of audio stream URLs, like this one:
http://popplers5.bandcamp.com/download/track?enc=mp3-128&id=1269403107&stream=1
(which, by the way, are from the incredible bandcamp . com)

I need to know how to use these with audio streaming scripts like the wpaudio plugin (wpaudio . com)
Most of these plugins require a link to an actual mp3 file. As you can see, the URL above is an audio stream, not an actual mp3. How do I put the two together?

If you visit that URL, your browser should start playing the audio stream. I basically need to be able to embed the audio stream into a web page.

Thanks!

Comment: in Google Chrome, if you 'right-click' on the page and select 'save as' it will give you the option to save as an .mp3 file. Pretty cool, wouldn't have known that if I didn't see your post. Also, cool song.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mplayer:

```
mplayer -dumpstream url
```

Check this page:

- http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/streaming.html

for more information.

If this is not a live stream thing, as it looks like for the above file, you can use a simple wget:

```
wget "http://popplers5.bandcamp.com/download/track?enc=mp3-128&id=1269403107&stream=1" -O outfile.mp3
```

Be sure to check copyright/licensing of the content before you do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPaudio or any of the others you want, no problem.  There is absolutely no difference between that stream URL you posted, and a random MP3 file served up from somewhere.  At least, not from your browser's perspective.

Your browser has no idea, and does not care, how the source server gets its content.  It's all HTTP, and the only thing your browser cares about is content type.  Here's what that looks like:

`Content-Type: audio/mpeg`

Same as it would be if you tossed an MP3 up there.  No biggie.

Use WPaudio, or any other web MP3 player.  They all will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but WPaudio does not recognize this URL as an mp3 file. Any ideas on how I can get it to do so?